# Why are my questions not being answered

Tags: support

On stackoverflow I have asked a total of 12 questions. Out of these 12 questions 5 of them have been answered. These questions are often the ones that I spend the most time on.

These question are often the most complex (which could be the reason) and normally get low views. These question almost never get downvotes and rarely get comments. So far I can only say that one of these questions were unanswered due to a lack of information.

Here is my most recent unanswered question:
[Email send attempt responded with: Error: Mail command failed: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425456/email-send-attempt-responded-with-error-mail-command-failed-555-5-5-2-syntax)

> When trying to send a nodemailer email I am getting the error: Error: Mail command failed: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error. After doing some research I found out it had to do with an issue with the from address. However I have checked and double checked that the addresses are valid and they are definitely are.
>
> A while ago I made a library. This library used classes in order to: send emails, watch files, query dataBases etc. Now I am trying to use this library to send email notifications for an app I am building. However the above described error occurred. I have tried wrapping my recipient and from addresses in , with no results. This error occurs even when using the exact same code as I used before and since then I have made no changes to my gmail settings.
>
> Here is my library code (yes I do know it is poorly written, I'm just too lazy to refactor it):
>
> Important lines: 32-51, 64-90
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @file A file that contains the "dataBase" class.
>  */
>
> Object.prototype.size = function() {
>   let size = 0
>   for(let i of Object.keys(this)) {
>     size += 1
>   }
>   return size
> }
>
> const fs = require('fs');
> const adodb = require('node-adodb')
> adodb.debug = true
>
> /**
>  * @constructor 
>  * @param {string} connection - The connection string to the database.
>  * @param {boolean} X64  - Whether or not you are using the 64 bit version.
>  * @name dataBase
>  * @description A class for: connecting, Querying, etc, Microsoft access databases.
>  */
>
> exports.dataBase = class dataBase {
>   constructor(connection, X64) {
>     this.connectString = connection
>     this.X64 = X64
>     this.connection = adodb.open(connection, X64)
>     this._this = this
>     this.shortcuts = require('./shortcuts')
>   }
>
> /**
>    * @async
>    * @function dataBase#close
>    * @description Closes the connection to the database.
>    */
>
> async close() {
>     await this.connection.close()
>     return
>   }
>
> /**
>    * @async
>    * @function dataBase#reopen
>    * @description Reopens the connection to the database if it has been closed.
>    */
>
> async reopen() {
>     this.connection = adodb.open(this.connectString, this.X64)
>     return
>   }
>
> async shortcut(type, data) {
>     await this.shortcuts.data[type](data, this._this)
>     return 
>   }
>
> /**
>    * @async
>    * @function dataBase#runSQL
>    * @param {string} SQL - The SQL that will be run.
>    * @description Runs any valid SQL on the database.
>    * @returns {object[]|object} If the SQL is a query, this is the result.
>    */
>
> async runSQL(sql) {
>     let type
>     if(sql.match('SELECT')) {
>       type = 'query'
>     } else {
>       type = 'execute'
>     }
>     let data
>     let self = this
>     await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>       self.connection[type](sql).then(result => {
>         data = result
>         resolve()
>       }).catch(err => {
>         console.log(err)
>       })
>     }).catch(err => {
>       console.log(err)
>     })
>     return data
>   }
>
> /**
>    * @async
>    * @function dataBase#query
>    * @param {string} table - The table that you are querying.
>    * @param {string[]|string} [columns] - The column(s) you want to query - If left empty or as '*' it will query all columns.
>    * @param {string[]|string} [rows] - The ID of the row(s) you want to query - If left empty or as '*' it will query all rows.
>    * @param {string[]|string} [options] - Any additional paramiters in the query - If left empty there will be no additional paramiters.
>    * @description Runs a query based on the four paramiters described below. Here are all of it's child functions.
>    * @returns {object[]} The result of the query.
>    */
>
>  async query(table, columns = '*' || [], rows = '*' || [], options = '*' || []) {
>     function makeArray(str) {
>       if(typeof str === 'string' && str !== '*') {
>         return [str]
>       }
>     }
>
>    makeArray(columns)
>     makeArray(rows)
>     makeArray(options)
>
>    function processData(table, columns, rows, options) {
>       function processColumns(columns) {
>         let retval = ''
>         for(let i in columns) {
>           if(i != columns.length - 1) {
>             retval += `${columns[i]},`
>           } else {
>             retval += `${columns[i]}`
>             return retval
>           }
>         }
>
>      }
>
>      function processRows(rows) {
>         let retval = ''
>         for(let i in rows) {
>           if(i != rows.length - 1) {
>             retval += `ID=${rows[i]} AND `
>           } else {
>             retval += `ID=${rows[i]}`
>           }
>         }
>         return retval
>       }
>
>     function processOptions(options) {
>         let retval = ''
>         for(let i in rows) {
>             retval += ` AND ${options[i]}`
>         }
>         return retval
>       }
>
>      let SQLcolumns = processColumns(columns)
>       let SQLrows = processRows(rows)
>       let SQLoptions = processOptions(options)
>
>    if(rows === '*' && options === '*') {
>         return `SELECT ${SQLcolumns} FROM [${table}];`
>       } else if(options === '*') {
>         return `SELECT ${SQLcolumns} FROM [${table}] WHERE ${SQLrows};`
>       } else if(rows === '*') {
>         return `SELECT ${SQLcolumns} FROM [${table}] WHERE ${SQLoptions};`
>       } else {
>         return `SELECT ${SQLcolumns} FROM [${table}] WHERE ${SQLrows}${SQLoptions};`
>       }
>     }
>
>    let data
>     await this.runSQL(processData(table, columns, rows, options)).then((result) => {
>       data = result
>     }).catch(err => {
>       console.log(err)
>     })
>     return data
>   }
>
>  /**
>    * @async
>    * @function dataBase#createTable
>    * @param {string} name - The name of the table that will be made.
>    * @param {object} columns - The columns in the table, for each property the key is the column name and the value is the column type.
>    * @param {object} [rows] - The rows to initially add to the dataBase, if left blank there will be no inital rows. - In each property the value will be the value inserted into the column, the column is determined by the order of the properties.
>    * @description Creates a table based on the peramiters below.
>    */
>
>  async createTable(name, columns, rows = null) {
>     function processColumns(columns) {
>       let retval = ''
>       for(let i of Object.keys(columns)) {
>         if(i !== Object.keys(columns)[columns.size() - 1]) {
>           retval += `${i} ${columns[i]},\n`
>         } else {
>           retval += `${i} ${columns[i]}`
>         }
>       }
>       return retval
>     }
>     let data
>     let SQLcolumns = processColumns(columns)
>
>    await this.runSQL(`CREATE TABLE ${name} (\n${SQLcolumns}\n);`).then((result) => {
>       data = result
>     })  
>
>    if(rows !== null) {
>       this.addRecords(name, rows)
>     }
>   }
>
>  /**
>    * @async
>    * @function dataBase#addRecords
>    * @param {string} table - The name of the the table that the rows will be inserted into.
>    * @param {object} values - The rows to add to the dataBase, if left blank there will be no inital rows. - In each property the value will be the value inserted into the column, the column is determined by the order of the properties.
>    * @description Adds records to a database based on the peramiters below.
>    */
>
>  async addRecords(table, values) {
>     let data = []
>     function processValues(values) {
>       let retval = ''
>       for(let i of Object.keys(values)) {
>         if(i !== Object.keys(values)[values.size() - 1]) {
>           retval += `${values[i]}, `
>         } else {
>           retval += values[i]
>         }
>       }
>       return retval
>     }
>
>    for(let i of values) {
>       let SQLvalues
>       SQLvalues = processValues(i)
>       await this.runSQL(`INSERT INTO [${table}] VALUES (${SQLvalues});`).then((result) => {
>         data.push(result)
>       })
>     }
>
>    return data
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The constructor works by taking a email and password and then creating a nodeMailer transporter with those credentials.
>
> The send function works by sending a nodemailer email with the first parameter being the recipient email, the second being the body, the third being the subject and the forth being advanced options.
>
> The from field is the email that was inputted in the constructor.
>
> And here is my code that I am running:
>
> ```
> let data = require('./index.js')
>
> let gmail = new data.email('redacted@gmail.com', 'redacted')
>
> gmail.send('redacted@icloud.com', 'testing testing', 'test', {
>
> }).catch(err => {
>   console.log(err)
> })
> ```
>
> Note: when I say email most of the time I mean email address.
>
> Expected results: Email is sent,
>
> actual results:
>
> ```
> { Error: Mail command failed: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error. l12sm3853378pgn.83 - gsmtp
>     at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Application\Libraries\Data-comms\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:774:19)
>     at SMTPConnection._actionMAIL (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Application\Libraries\Data-comms\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1539:34)
>     at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Application\Libraries\Data-comms\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1026:18)
>     at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Application\Libraries\Data-comms\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:933:20)
>     at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Application\Libraries\Data-comms\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:739:14)
>     at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Application\Libraries\Data-comms\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:691:47)
>     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
>     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
>     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
>     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
>   code: 'EENVELOPE',
>   response: '555 5.5.2 Syntax error. l12sm3853378pgn.83 - gsmtp',
>   responseCode: 555,
>   command: 'MAIL FROM' }
> ```
>
> Nodemailer version: 5.1.1
>
> Gmail settings:
>
> Experimental Access: off
>
> Send mail as: MyFull Name
>
> POP is enabled
>
> IMAP is enabled

As you can see there are no help center issues with this code so,

**My Question is:** why are these questions not being answered

Other questions:
[`NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id` when using selenium, even though application is working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080916/nosuchsessionerror-invalid-session-id-when-using-selenium-even-though-applic)
[How to document a nested function within a method in JSdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775705/how-to-document-a-nested-function-within-a-method-in-jsdoc)

There are 2 others but they are less important.

Comment: Your counting seems to be off. There are 7 questions with answers (6 of those you accepted) and another one that is a duplicate so you also got an answer for that (not on your own question but still answered) and another one that can't be answered because the problem was somewhere else as you stated in your own answer.

Comment: You asked this question 3 hours ago.

Comment: @Cody Gray oops, guess I wrote the wrong one, the other three are still very old though so the question still remains

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> why are these questions not being answered

There could be many reasons:

- It could be that your question is not interesting; the first thing that I thought when I saw your question was '*There's just too much going on here.*', maybe I'm wrong and you've got the right amount of text to code ratio, but to me, at a glance it seemed like a wall of text and code. This seems consistent with the rest of your posts, remember, detail is good, but only the relevant details
- It could be that your question is about a niche topic which not many people are into thus making it harder to find people who could answer it
- It could be that the time you ask your question is when most of the active users (in that tag or even site wide) are sleeping or busy. Don't forget, the contributors have normal day-to-day lives too

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080916/nosuchsessionerror-invalid-session-id-when-using-selenium-even-though-applic) of the other questions you linked has an answer, so I'm not sure why you linked it? The timestamps show that the time between asking and answering was quite short too (asked: `Mar 9 at 19:03`, answered: `Mar 9 at 19:39`).

If you want to get more attention to your questions, you could participate by answering, editing questions, or asking more useful questions and then attach bounties to your questions through your newly earned rep.

Just a final note, no one is obligated to answer your question and neither are you guaranteed to get an answer. Secondly, you not getting answers to your questions probably isn't anything personal.

Comment: I fully agree with your final note, I just wanted to get some insight on how to get my future questions answered